# My boolean code didn't work for notice wrong username and password

Tags: php, html

i'm write code boolean for login page and set username and password that will be directed to new page if that true, but if false i want to print notice if that username and password wrong, but the code i write didn't do it, i need help, what wrong with my code?

I have tried to find what is wrong with my code and look for it on the internet, and I don't know what else to do, I'm a student

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST["submit"]) ){
if( $_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "123" ){
  header("Location: admin.php");
  exit;
} else {
  $error = true;
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>login admin</h1>
<?php if ( isset($error) ) : ?>
  <p style="color: red; font-style: italic">wrong username or password! 
   </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<ul>

<form action="admin.php" method="post">
  <li>
    <label for="username">username : </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="password">password : </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
  </li>
</form>
```

i expect that prints a notification if the username and password are wrong

Comment: where do you attempt to echo a message?

Comment: `$error = true;` doesn't print anything and never will.

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell this, i will print that inside html, and this is the code <?php if ( isset($error) ) : ?>
      <p style="color: red; font-style: italic">wrong username or password!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

Comment: What are the physical names of your script files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your form is posting directly to `admin.php` when in fact, you want your current script to handle the form.

Remove `action="admin.php"` from your form so that it posts to itself. Then, when your script processes the form, it will handle the redirect for you.

```
<form method="post">
   ...
```

OR

Change the action to the name of your current script.

```
<form action="name_of_script.php" method="post">
   ...
```

You're missing your closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean this?

```
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            if ($_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "123") {
                header("Location: admin.php");
                exit;
            } else {
                echo 'username or password is incorrect';
                exit;
            }
        }
```

Comment: code should have an explanation so OP understands the issue